# Identifying an algorithm described as 'Tukey approach' for ignoring outliers?

Tags: regression, robust, total-least-squares

MVTec's machine vision library Halcon has an operator `fit_line_contour_xld` for robustly fitting lines to 2D points. Here's the documentation entry for that operator: https://www.mvtec.com/doc/halcon/13/en/fit_line_contour_xld.html

The default is the `tukey` line fit. I'd like to know more about how it works, what its strengths and weaknesses are. Unfortunately, it doesn't really go into too much detail on the actual algorithm used and I've had no luck searching for the answer online.

Can someone here maybe decipher which algorithm this `tukey` variant represents?

As for the hints, I can tell you that it's probably some form of orthogonal regression because it's meant for fitting lines to points extracted from a 2D image. Here are parts of the documentation I believe are relevant:

> 'tukey': Weighted 'least squares' line fitting, where outliers are
>   ignored based on the approach of Tukey (see below).
>
> (...)
>
> For 'huber', 'tukey', and 'drop' a robust error statistics is used to
>   estimate the standard deviation of the distances from the contour
>   points without outliers from the approximating line. The parameter
>   ClippingFactor (a scaling factor for the standard deviation) controls
>   the amount of outliers: The smaller the value chosen for
>   ClippingFactor the more outliers are detected. The detection of
>   outliers is repeated. The parameter Iterations specifies the number of
>   iterations. (...) Note that in the approach of Tukey ('tukey'), the
>   outliers are removed before performing the approximation and all other
>   points are weighted, whereas in the approach of Huber ('huber'), the
>   outliers still have a small influence. Particularly, for outliers the
>   optimization is influenced linearly and for points with a smaller
>   distance it is influenced quadratically. In practice, the approach of
>   Tukey is recommended.

Comment: Be careful! From your title and opening sentences you appeared to be asking about a different thing to that which is actually operating. Fortunately the quote helps

Comment: @Glen Thanks for the tip. Hopefully I made the title a bit more aligned with the contents now?

Comment: Well, it's less likely to be confused for a Tukey three group line, (though not everyone would describe what I assume is intended to be Tukey's biweight that way). It should suffice.